# Translating Stata Code to R: survey weights

Tags: r, stata, survey, weighting

I'm trying to weight survey data in R. I'm using Stata code as a reference.

The code used on that program to weight my data was:

```
svyset [iw=wgtp], vce(sdr), sdrweight(wgtp1-wgtp80) mse
```

I translated that code into R code like this:

```
svydesign(ids = ~1, data = house.data, weights = (~wgtp1-wgtp80))
```

However I am unsure whether this is a correct translation and if I am applying this correctly in R. Any insight and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hi, that doesn't look correct..  maybe see table two of https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009-2/RJournal_2009-2_Damico.pdf and also the note on pdf page 63 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf  ?

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of 'survey', you want

```
svrepdesign(data=house.data, weights=~wgtp, repweights="wgtp[1-9]+",type="successive-difference")
```

That is `svrepdesign` for a survey with replicate weights, sampling weights `wgtp`, and replicate weights `wgtp1-wgtp80`, and "successive difference" weights.